# Webform submission: how to send the translation of a variable by mail

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, drupal-form-submission

In a Drupal project, i have a basic weborm. As soon as the user submits one, an email is send with all the things he just wrote.

Example:

Imp_First_Name:%value[firstname]
Imp_Last_Name:%value[lastname]
Imp_City:%value[lastname]
Imp_Country:%value[country]
Imp_Email:%value[email]
Imp_Subject:%value[subject]
I have a problem on this line:

Imp_Subject:%value[subject]
Subject contains what the user have selected within a select list. My problem is when the website is set to chinese, all is written in chinese obviously but i don't want the chinese version to be sent. I need the english one.

For example :

In my webform, the user has the choice between 3 countries:

Afghanistan|阿富汗
Afrique du Sud|南非
Albanie|阿尔巴尼亚
I need the country name in latin alphabet ! How can i manage to do this?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky one...
There is substitution and also two possible template layers. One comes from webform and second comes from mailsystem / mail handler module.

I'm assuming that the substitution is done before the template layer so the t() function should be applied either within a hook on that level or within the proper template file.

Debugging with XDebug would really help to solve the issue.